# How do I get the time of the highest quote of the day in KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've got a table `q`:

```
t                             ap     bp     s    m
--------------------------------------------------------
2023.01.03D09:29:00.527999180 130.55 130.51 0.04 130.53
2023.01.03D09:29:00.528127764 130.54 130.51 0.03 130.525
2023.01.03D09:29:00.528406582 130.54 130.51 0.03 130.525
2023.01.03D09:29:00.532340845 130.54 130.51 0.03 130.525
2023.01.03D09:29:00.534640830 130.54 130.51 0.03 130.525
2023.01.03D09:29:00.560375666 130.55 130.51 0.04 130.53
2023.01.03D09:29:01.856393774 130.55 130.51 0.04 130.53
```

I'm trying to extract the `t` for `max m` from `q`.

My query is:

```
select from q where (t.date,m) in (select max m by t.date from q)
```

This gives me `'length` error on the `in`. I'm sure my query isn't right, but I'm not sure what the 'right' way to do it is.

How do I extract the complete row with the `max m` by `t.date`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `fby`

```
select from q where m=(max;m)fby([]`date$t)
```

Note that this may return more than one row per date if the same max price repeats